# sed : Sustitute char "A" in a portion of a string and keep it in other portions

Tags: regex, sed, substring, substitution

All is in the title :

here is the string pattern of a multi-line file:

```
foo_bar_alpha = "a1b2c3_cat_andthis"  
barfoo_bar_alpha = "just a int number"  
loremfoo_bar_beta = "192.168.0.0"  
... other lines come here ...
```

Using sed (and/or awk and/or perl), I need to substitute char "_" with "." , but only in the first part of the string, which is right delimited by "=", and keep the 2nd part (after "=").

Sthg like :

```
sed "s/(.*)=(.*)/ \1 with "_" replaced by "." = \2/g" < my_file
                   ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
                          how to do that ?
```

Thx in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk '{gsub("_",".",$1)}1' ./infile
```

#### Input

```
$ cat ./infile
foo_bar_alpha = "a1b2c3_cat_andthis"
barfoo_bar_alpha = "just a int number"
loremfoo_bar_beta = "192.168.0.0"
```

#### Output

```
$ awk '{gsub("_",".",$1)}1' ./infile
foo.bar.alpha = "a1b2c3_cat_andthis"
barfoo.bar.alpha = "just a int number"
loremfoo.bar.beta = "192.168.0.0"
```

**Note*: If you for sure need to delimit on `=` because your variable names somehow contain spaces (highly doubtful) then this works:

```
awk -F= '{gsub("_",".",$1)}1' OFS="=" ./infile
```

Comment: not far away :-), I need to keep also "=" inbetween both parts, testing right now

Comment: @hornetbzz check my answer again. I updated it before you commented

Comment: @Eelvex ya, added a note to take care of that case. However, I don't think it's needed due to the nature of his input being variable names.

Comment: @SiegeX, may be needed in case there are spaces in $1.

Comment: @kurumi doesn't matter, `awk` will not count leading spaces as a field

Comment: @SiegeX: thx and impressive - result looks ok :-) Thx also to Elvex.

Comment: @Siegex, what i mean is if the delimiter is not set to "=", then words such as "foo.bar.alpha some words" will produce `$1 = foo.bar.alpha`. I saw you added the *note in your answer. That should be what i am talking about.

Comment: @SiegeX and @kurumi : it's not a big deal as the left pattern really matches "foo_bar_lorem_other" always, with one up to 5 "_". And now I know how to handle that. Thx again.

Answer (score 2):

Crude but effective:

```
sed 'h;s/.*=/=/;x;s/=.*//;s/_/\./g;G;s/\n//' filename
```

Comment: Thx. Works as well. I've been trying for hours to find that one !!! I need to know your secret ;-)

Comment: changed as follow : sed 'h;s/.*=/=/;x;s/=.*//;s/_/./g;G;s/\n//' < my_file

Comment: @hornetbzz do you get how it works? If not I (or Beta) can explain it to you.

Comment: @hornetbzz: secret? I just reach for the hold space as soon as I get stuck. (Dennis Williamson: thanks, +1).

Comment: @SiegeX and @Beta: thx guys. Currently reading (once again) the sed man page and using this by steps, so I hope I'll get it.

Comment: Here is my understanding of this impressive sed usage :
h : capture the right hand portion into the hold space, based on "=" delimiter,  
x : swap the hold space with pattern space so result looks as unchanged,  
s/=.*// : removes the right hand portion of the pattern space,  
s/_/./g : the substitution itself on the whole string of the pattern space,  
G : Restore the hold space to the pattern space,  
 s/\n// : Remove LF added by "G"

Comment: @hornetbzz close but not quite.  1) copy the *entire* pattern space to hold space. 2) remove the left-hand portion but not including the '=' from the pattern space 3) swap pattern with hold space 4) remove the right-hand portion including the '=' from the new pattern space 5) make the _ -> . substitution 6) append the hold space (holds right-hand portion) to the pattern space 7) remove the newline added by 'G'

Answer (score 1):

use awk instead of sed

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="="}{gsub("_",".",$1)}1' file

ruby -F"=" -ane '$F[0].gsub!(/_/,".");print $F.join("=")' file
```

Comment: Thx it works as well. Could you pls tell what means the last 1 in "awk...}1" ?

Comment: that is "shortcut" for `{print}`